# Bug in QtLocation/Android? JNI_OnLoad never called -> crash on nullpointer access

Tags: android, c++, qt, android-ndk, location

I've been investigating on a [Qt5/Android/Location issue](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42237283/qt5-qgeopositioninfosourcecreatedefaultsource-crashes-on-android-5-0) and found a nullpointer access which makes me think GPS with Qt5 cannot work on any machine.

In my case when I try to run

```
auto source = QGeoPositionInfoSource::createDefaultSource(this);
```

the method `AttachedJNIEnv::AttachedJNIEnv()` defined in `src/plugins/position/android/src/jnipositioning.cpp` (Qt5 sources) crashes with the following call:

```
if (javaVM->GetEnv((void**)&jniEnv, JNI_VERSION_1_6) < 0) {
```

On at least three devices I've tried, `javaVM` is `NULL` so I'm pretty sure it's not just an issue with my device.

`javaVM` is a global pointer (what a shame..) and it *should* get a value in `Q_DECL_EXPORT jint JNICALL JNI_OnLoad(JavaVM *, void *)` also defined in `jnipositioning.cpp`

**My question is now:**

Obviously this is a bug in Qt5 and I'll make a bug report. But in the meanwhile I'd like to get positioning working with some sort of fix/workaround.
So what can be the reason for `JNI_OnLoad()` not being called? Did I forget to somehow initialize `Qt::Location`? Who should call `JNI_OnLoad()`? Can I do this manually in some way?

**Update:**

I've reported a [Qt bug](https://bugreports.qt.io/browse/QTBUG-59010) now.